# plotting multiple sets of different data points on a graph in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot several sets of ordered pairs on the same plot, using R. I don't need a line between them, because that's already taken care of by a simple linear regression. Here's some sample code:

```
sw_sd <- c(0, 20)
sw_r <- c(5, 10)
aa_sd <- c(0, 16)
aa_r <- c(5, 8)
png("5-airline-cals.png")
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,25), ylim=c(0,12))
plot(c(aa_sd, aa_r))
plot(sw_sd,sw_r, pch=22, main="Capital Allocation Lines", xlab="Standard Deviation", ylab="Expected Return")
sw_cal=lm(sw_r~sw_sd)
aa_cal=lm(aa_r~aa_sd)
abline(sw_cal, col="forestgreen", lwd=3)
abline(aa_cal, col="blue", lwd=3)
legend(1, 9, c("Southwest Airlines","American Airlines"), cex=0.8, col=c("forestgreen","blue"), lwd=3);
box()
dev.off()
```

The `sd` pairs are the x coordinates, and the `r` are the y coordinates. I need both sets of x-y pairs on the same scatter plot. This is simplified data, but you get the idea.

Comment: See `?points`, `?lines` and from the looks of your code reading `?plot` with a particular attention to the examples wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I've been looking at the documentation for `lines` and `plot`, but I'm still not sure what you're thinking. Should I be using `lines` instead of `abline`? I used `lines` initially, but I need the lines to extend *past* the points, not just connect them (since the points represent continuous functions over an interval). Can you provide me with a bit more detail about specifically *where* I should improve? As I'm new to R, that would certainly be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for the drive by RTFM comment. Here's some more detail.

Using base graphics, I would accomplish what you're doing via something like this:

```
plot(c(sw_sd,aa_sd),c(sw_r,aa_r), pch = 22, 
        col = rep(c('forestgreen','blue'),each = 2),main="Capital Allocation Lines", 
        xlab="Standard Deviation", ylab="Expected Return")
abline(lm(sw_r~sw_sd),col = 'forestgreen',lwd = 3)
abline(lm(aa_r~aa_sd),col = 'blue',lwd = 3)
```

The reason I mentioned `points` and `lines` was because you were asking how to plot multiple sets of points on the same graph. The general strategy with base graphics in R is you initialize a plot with a single call to `plot` and then you *add* to it using things like `points`, `lines`, `abline` etc.

Your calls to `plot.new` and `plot.window` aren't really necessary; if you're just starting with R you probably won't need to use them for a while, really.

In general, each time you call `plot`, R will start a new plotting device. So your repeated calls to `plot` are just going back and starting over again. You'll notice that your resulting plot didn't end up having y axis limits of 0 to 12. That's because each time you called `plot` anew you were starting over from scratch, as if the previous commands never happened. This is also why the other set of points didn't appear.

Finally, the recommendation to read `?plot` was a bit misleading, since really `?plot.default` is a bit more informative for beginners. It has little nuggets like being able to pass x and y axis limits directly, passing `type = "n"` to create an empty plot with the right dimensions that you can then add to, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help; that really simplifies what I'm trying to do and gives me a good learning boost.

Answer (score 3):

A quick `ggplot`-based answer:

```
dat <- data.frame(sd=c(0,20,0,16),
                  r=c(5,10,5,8),
                  airline=rep(c("Southwest","American"),each=2))

library(ggplot2)
theme_update(theme_bw())
qplot(sd,r,data=dat,colour=airline)+geom_smooth(method="lm")+
  labs(x="Standard Deviation",y="Expected Return")+
  scale_colour_manual(value=c("forestgreen","blue"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the data frame of Ben but with lattice:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(r~sd, data=dat, groups=airline,
   type=c('p', 'r'),
   auto.key=list(space='right'),
   main="Capital Allocation Lines",
   xlab="Standard Deviation", ylab="Expected Return")
```

You will find detailed information in `?panel.xyplot` and `?xyplot`.